# Show new window with a different icon in taskbar (PyQt5)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a button on the main window which when clicked opens a "sub" window. For the "sub" window I have set a different icon because I want the two windows to be shown as "separate" applications, however, in the taskbar the two windows are grouped, and only when I hover over it does it show the different icons (next to the name) for the two windows.

Is there any way I can open the new window in a separate icon/group in the taskbar?

Thank you

Here is the function I am connecting to the button in the main window:

```
def openSubWindow(self):
    self.w2 = subWindow()
    self.w2.show()
```

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to "ungroup" applications in the taskbar. But you could at least try with [`QApplication.setWindowIcon()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#windowIcon-prop) and switch it whenever the active window changes.

Comment: That sounds like a good workaround, although being able to ungroup them would have been better. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that Windows does it on its own, and as far as I know the only way to avoid it (except than completely disable the feature system-wide), is to have different processes that have unique application ids.